Old SF movie with bald people, a radiation and mysterious cave
I am looking for an older SF movie (from the 50s-70s). My friend remembers only one scene in which, immortal people are after radiation. They are probably skin is gray or silver in color, they are completely bald and hiding in underground caverns. They are reached by people from the surface of the planet, who have become immune to radiation or survived it. A scene similar to that of Beneath the Planet of the Apes, where there they meet these old people in the underground.  The silver people were similar to these from "The Creation of the Humanoids" (1962).
It isn't "Time Machine" (1960), although Morlocks are some similar, but they aren't bald.

Sounds like ST:TOS The Cage! ☺ https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/2/24/Talosians_3.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20190309003202&path-prefix=en

Thank you very much. I will check this.

This sounds like Beneath the Planet of the Apes (1970), the first sequel to the original Planet of the Apes.  It features a subterranean city populated by mutated humans, the descendants of survivors of a nuclear war.  They are bald (some of them), dress in gray, are telepathic, and worship an atomic bomb.
There are also some apes in the film.


"Some apes". I've seen this and there are in fact several apes. Possibly even approaching a multiplicity.

@Valorum More like a plethora.

@NJohnny - A veritable barrelful, so to speak.

A cornucopia of chimps.
